# Get picture From Camera/Gallery and send it to server in android

Tags: android, camera, gallery

what i want is,
take picture from camera or gallery and convert that to base64 and sent it to the server.
for this i did following code:

```
case R.id.btn_take_photo:
    boolean iNetStatus = Utility.isNetworkAvaliable(mContext);
    if (iNetStatus == true) {
       openImageIntent();
    } else {
        Utility.internetErrorDialog(mContext);
    }
break;

private void openImageIntent() {

    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);

    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }


    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Source");

    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQ_IMAGE_CHANGE);
}

public String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap immagex = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
    immagex.setDensity(100);

    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;
}

switch (requestCode) {

    case REQ_IMAGE_CHANGE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {

                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    isCamera = MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.equals(data
                            .getAction());
                }
                Uri selectedImageUri;
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                    iUserPhoto.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                            bitmap, 100, 100, false));
                    base64Image = encodeTobase64(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 400, 400, false));
                    boolean iNetStatus = haveInternet(DeviceSearchActivity.this);
                    if (iNetStatus == true) {
                        new changePhotoToServer().execute();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("INTERNET", "NO INTERNET");
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    default:
        Log.e(TAG, "Unknown request code");
        break;
    }
}
```

while i am executing this code, i am getting chooser of camera and gallery, clicking on gallery i am able to select picture and clicking on camera i am able to capture picture but in both case while i am clicking on OK my app is crashing. It gives following error:

```
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): java.lang.RuntimeException:   Unable to resume activity    {com.ampl.bna/com.ampl.bna.RecipeDetailsFragmentActivity}:    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,     request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity     {com.ampl.bna/com.ampl.bna.RecipeDetailsFragmentActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3200)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3238)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2525)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,  request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity  {com.ampl.bna/com.ampl.bna.RecipeDetailsFragmentActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3821)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3174)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     ... 12 more
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:452)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:855)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at com.ampl.bna.RecipeDetailsFragmentActivity.onActivityResult(RecipeDetailsFragmentActivity.java:609)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5385)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3817)
03-10 13:01:56.904: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     ... 13 more
```

can you please take some time to help me by solving this problem?
it will be great help. Thank you.

Comment: Your log tells it: you have a NullPointerException in RecipeDetailsFragmentActivity.java:609. Which line is that?

Comment: Line 609 : Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
        getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);

Comment: Now please read the log carefully! OpenInputStream fails. What do you think is null? You can test that before executing line 609. Or better yet before the `try`.

Comment: i am not getting any idea, can you please help me?

Comment: OpenInputStream fails you can read. Now which variable/parameter would it use to open a stream from? You know it's called by getBitmap().

Comment: i am getting null path for image, i don't know why

Comment: null path for image? What do you mean? Please be exact. What is null? Which variable of yours?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap( getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri); in this line the Uri variable selectedImageUri is getting null value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72663/discussion-between-rajesh-suthar-and-greenapps).

Comment: Yes indeed. selectedImageUri==null. You understand why? That happens here `selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();`. So check for null before the `try` and do not continue with the try if it is null but instead display a toast saying so and return.